# android application dequeuebuffer error on snapdragon device

Tags: android, deque

I got some strange crash when running our android application on snapdragon device, but thing works well on other devices.
Here are some logs before process die:

```
W/Adreno-EGLSUB( 3075): <DequeueBuffer:583>: dequeue native buffer fail: Unknown error 2147483646, buffer=0x0, handle=0x0
W/Adreno-EGLSUB( 3075): <SwapBuffers:1300>: Invalid native buffer. Failed to queueBuffer
W/Adreno-EGLSUB( 3075): <updater_thread:456>: native buffer is NULL
D/QCUtilClass( 2464): extended extractor not needed, return default.
```

and:

```
E/BufferQueue(  357): [xxx.xxxx.xxxxx(our game app)] dequeueBuffer: can't dequeue multiple buffers without setting the buffer count
W/Adreno-EGLSUB( 3075): <DequeueBuffer:583>: dequeue native buffer fail: Invalid argument, buffer=0x0, handle=0x0
W/Adreno-ES20( 3075): <gl2_surface_swap:43>: GL_OUT_OF_MEMORY
W/Adreno-EGL( 3075): <qeglDrvAPI_eglSwapBuffers:3590>: EGL_BAD_SURFACE
```

.....

Any help will be appreciate.
Thanks.

Comment: I see the same on a Hisense "pulse" Google TV; not clear what the problem is. E/BufferQueue﹕dequeueBuffer: can't dequeue multiple buffers without setting the buffer count

Comment: any details on what the app is trying to do ?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like it's fired from here [BufferQueue](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/native/+/tools_r21/libs/gui/BufferQueue.cpp) line 401. Buffer size initialized inside queue constructor.

Try to disable hardware acceleration in Android manifest. Looks like it's gonna help. If so, do this programmatically depend on OS version or device CPU. More like it's modern Android OS version bug.